# How do I disable jQuery keypress detection when focused on certain HTML element?

Tags: jquery, html

currently my web page enabled a key detection feature, when hitting A and D, it changes pictures (image source). I just added a login, sign up feature, but when I enter username or password I sometimes hit A and D, the pictures change, which I don't want, how do I disable the pic-changing feature when the login element is focused?

I am thinking that since the document selector selects the entire page, is there a way to exclude certain element? Or is there another way to achieve what I want?

```
<div id="loginContainer">
 Username:<br/> <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
 Password:<br/> <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
 <input type="button" name="login" value="Login"/>
</div>

----------

$(document).keypress(function(e){
        // key press detection code here
});
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`document.activeElement` return focused item. you can check it to check if it is certain element or not. in each jQuery funtion if you `return false;` its act like disabled function

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
         if(document.activeElement && document.activeElement != document.body)
             return false;
         // key press detection code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the element is focused and return:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if( $("input[name='login']").is( ":focus" )) return; 
    // key press detection code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false;
});
```